# How can I use a wildcard in a vb.net line.contains that is surrounded by double quotes

Tags: json, vb.net

I have some vb.net code

```
   Dim reader As New StreamReader("C:\geoData\zipCodes.geojson", Encoding.Default)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Dim lines As Integer = 0
    While (reader.Peek() <> -1)

If line.Contains("""ZCTA5CE20"": ""47236""") Then
```

And it works perfectly finding that line in a 2.5 gig json file.  However, I need to find all lines that contain

```
If line.Contains("""ZCTA5CE20"": ""47*""") Then
```

so I need a wildcard after the 47 but if I put in a * it is looking for a * followed by double quotes not a wildcard.  I still need the double quotes before the 47.

I have code that works it in as a JSON object but if I try to load the entire file it throws a memory error.

```
    Dim json = File.ReadAllText("C:\geoData\zipCodes.geojson")
    Dim ResultArray As New JArray
    Dim Jvalues As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Regex search.

```vb
Dim jsonRegex = New Regex("""ZCTA5CE20"":\ ""47.*?""", RegexOptions.Compiled)

If jsonRegex.IsMatch(line) Then
   ...
End If
```

In Regex `.` is a wildcard corresponding to one occurrence of any character. `*` means repeat this character zero, one or more times, the `?` means but as few times as possible. This`?` ensures that no quote is skipped, other wise `.*` would span up to the last double quote on the line. But as often with regex, there are several solutions to a problem. E.g., you can replace `.*?` by `\d*`. `\d` stands for one digit.

`\` escapes the following white space character.

You can use the [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) to loop through the lines one line at a time without loading the whole file at once.

```vb
Dim jsonRegex = New Regex("""ZCTA5CE20"":\ ""47.*?""", RegexOptions.Compiled)

For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("C:\geoData\zipCodes.geojson")
    If jsonRegex.IsMatch(line) Then
       ...
    End If
Next
```